# how can i replace time-series dataframe specific values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, time-series

I have the dataframes below (date/time is multi index) and I want to replace column values in (00:00:00~07:00:00) as a numpy array:

```
[[ 21.63920663  21.62012822  20.9900515   21.23217008  21.19482458
   21.10839656  20.89631935  20.79977166  20.99176729  20.91567565
   20.87258765  20.76210464  20.50357827  20.55897631  20.38005033
   20.38227309  20.54460993  20.37707293  20.08279925  20.09955877
   20.02559575  20.12390737  20.2917257   20.20056711  20.1589065
   20.41302289  20.48000767  20.55604102  20.70255192]]
```

```
     date        time    
2018-01-26  00:00:00    21.65
            00:15:00      NaN
            00:30:00      NaN
            00:45:00      NaN
            01:00:00      NaN
            01:15:00      NaN
            01:30:00      NaN
            01:45:00      NaN
            02:00:00      NaN
            02:15:00      NaN
            02:30:00      NaN
            02:45:00      NaN
            03:00:00      NaN
            03:15:00      NaN
            03:30:00      NaN
            03:45:00      NaN
            04:00:00      NaN
            04:15:00      NaN
            04:30:00      NaN
            04:45:00      NaN
            05:00:00      NaN
            05:15:00      NaN
            05:30:00      NaN
            05:45:00      NaN
            06:00:00      NaN
            06:15:00      NaN
            06:30:00      NaN
            06:45:00      NaN
            07:00:00      NaN
            07:15:00      NaN
            07:30:00      NaN
            07:45:00      NaN
            08:00:00      NaN
            08:15:00      NaN
            08:30:00      NaN
            08:45:00      NaN
            09:00:00      NaN
            09:15:00      NaN
            09:30:00      NaN
            09:45:00      NaN
            10:00:00      NaN
            10:15:00      NaN
            10:30:00      NaN
            10:45:00      NaN
            11:00:00      NaN
Name: temp, dtype: float64
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1.loc[idx[:, '00:00:00':'02:00:00'],:] = 1
```

Or if second levels are times:

```
import datetime

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1.loc[idx[:, datetime.time(0, 0, 0):datetime.time(2, 0, 0)],:] = 1
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df1)
                       aaa
date       time           
2018-01-26 00:00:00  21.65
           00:15:00    NaN
           00:30:00    NaN
           00:45:00    NaN
           01:00:00    NaN
           01:15:00    NaN
           01:30:00    NaN
           01:45:00    NaN
           02:00:00    NaN
           02:15:00    NaN
           02:30:00    NaN
           02:45:00    NaN
           03:00:00    NaN
2018-01-27 00:00:00   2.00
           00:15:00    NaN
           00:30:00    NaN
           00:45:00    NaN
           01:00:00    NaN
           01:15:00    NaN
           01:30:00    NaN
           01:45:00    NaN
           02:00:00    NaN
           02:15:00    NaN
           02:30:00    NaN
           02:45:00    NaN
           03:00:00    NaN
```

---

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1.loc[idx[:, '00:00:00':'02:00:00'],:] = 1
print (df1)
                     aaa
date       time         
2018-01-26 00:00:00  1.0
           00:15:00  1.0
           00:30:00  1.0
           00:45:00  1.0
           01:00:00  1.0
           01:15:00  1.0
           01:30:00  1.0
           01:45:00  1.0
           02:00:00  1.0
           02:15:00  NaN
           02:30:00  NaN
           02:45:00  NaN
           03:00:00  NaN
2018-01-27 00:00:00  1.0
           00:15:00  1.0
           00:30:00  1.0
           00:45:00  1.0
           01:00:00  1.0
           01:15:00  1.0
           01:30:00  1.0
           01:45:00  1.0
           02:00:00  1.0
           02:15:00  NaN
           02:30:00  NaN
           02:45:00  NaN
           03:00:00  NaN
```

EDIT:

For assign array is necessary use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeat by length of first level unique values:

```
df1.loc[idx[:, '00:00:00':'02:00:00'],:] = np.tile(np.arange(1, 10),len(df1.index.levels[0]))
print (df1)
                     aaa
date       time         
2018-01-26 00:00:00  1.0
           00:15:00  2.0
           00:30:00  3.0
           00:45:00  4.0
           01:00:00  5.0
           01:15:00  6.0
           01:30:00  7.0
           01:45:00  8.0
           02:00:00  9.0
           02:15:00  NaN
           02:30:00  NaN
           02:45:00  NaN
           03:00:00  NaN
2018-01-27 00:00:00  1.0
           00:15:00  2.0
           00:30:00  3.0
           00:45:00  4.0
           01:00:00  5.0
           01:15:00  6.0
           01:30:00  7.0
           01:45:00  8.0
           02:00:00  9.0
           02:15:00  NaN
           02:30:00  NaN
           02:45:00  NaN
           03:00:00  NaN
```

More general solution with generated array by length of slice:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
len0 = df1.loc[idx[df1.index.levels[0][0], '00:00:00':'02:00:00'],:].shape[0]
len1 = len(df1.index.levels[0])
df1.loc[idx[:, '00:00:00':'02:00:00'],:] = np.tile(np.arange(1, len0 + 1), len1)
```

---

Tested with `time`s:

```
import datetime
idx = pd.IndexSlice
arr =np.tile(np.arange(1, 10),len(df1.index.levels[0]))
df1.loc[idx[:, datetime.time(0, 0, 0):datetime.time(2, 0, 0)],:] = arr
print (df1)
                     aaa
date       time         
2018-01-26 00:00:00  1.0
           00:15:00  2.0
           00:30:00  3.0
           00:45:00  4.0
           01:00:00  5.0
           01:15:00  6.0
           01:30:00  7.0
           01:45:00  8.0
           02:00:00  9.0
           02:15:00  NaN
           02:30:00  NaN
           02:45:00  NaN
           03:00:00  NaN
2018-01-27 00:00:00  1.0
           00:15:00  2.0
           00:30:00  3.0
           00:45:00  4.0
           01:00:00  5.0
           01:15:00  6.0
           01:30:00  7.0
           01:45:00  8.0
           02:00:00  9.0
           02:15:00  NaN
           02:30:00  NaN
           02:45:00  NaN
           03:00:00  NaN
```

EDIT:

Last was problem found - my solution wokrs with one column `DataFrame`, but if working with `Series` need remove one `:`:

```
arr = np.array([[ 21.63920663, 21.62012822, 20.9900515, 21.23217008, 21.19482458, 21.10839656, 
                 20.89631935, 20.79977166, 20.99176729, 20.91567565, 20.87258765, 20.76210464,
                 20.50357827, 20.55897631, 20.38005033, 20.38227309, 20.54460993, 20.37707293, 
                 20.08279925, 20.09955877, 20.02559575, 20.12390737, 20.2917257, 20.20056711, 
                 20.1589065, 20.41302289, 20.48000767, 20.55604102, 20.70255192]])

import datetime
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1.loc[idx[:, datetime.time(0, 0, 0): datetime.time(7, 0, 0)]] = arr[0]
                                                          ---^^^
```

Comment: excellent .. i have one more question.. if i need to change value [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] .. then how can i apply ii?

Comment: Data are nice - always si same length of rows between `00:00:00` and `02:00:00` in all levels?

Comment: could you input 1~9 values as numpy array ?

Comment: It is `np.arange(1, 10)`

Comment: Could you chk  when multi index is datetine format  how to change cod?

Comment: Do you think `time`s in second level? How does work change `'00:00:00':'02:00:00'` to `datetime.time(0, 0, 0):datetime.time(2, 0, 0)` ? (untested)

Comment: it's weird... i got error msg "unhashable type: 'slice'" in df1.loc[idx[:,datetime.time(0, 0, 0):datetime.time(2, 0, 0)],:] = 1 ..

Comment: How working `print (df1.loc[idx[:,datetime.time(0, 0, 0):datetime.time(2, 0, 0)],:])` ?

Comment: "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Comment: Interesting, what return `print (type(df1.index.get_level_values(1)[0]))` ?

Comment: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: Are your real data confidental?

Comment: Hmmm, if assign scalar, also error? `df1.loc[idx[:, datetime.time(0, 0, 0):datetime.time(2, 0, 0)],:] = 1` ?

Comment: yes.. IndexingError: ((slice(None, None, None), slice(datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(2, 0), None)), slice(None, None, None))

Comment: I have no idea, is possivle share your real data with `df1.to_pickle('pkl1.pkl')` ?

Comment: how can i send it to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164401/discussion-between-jerry-han-and-jezrael).